# SVN to GIT with tags in root directory

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

I'm trying to create a new git repository from an old SVN repository that is structured like this:

```
/root
    trunk
    build_scripts
    packager
    0.1.0
    0.1.1
    0.1.2
    ...etc...
```

The 0.x would obviously traditionally be in a `tags` directory, and are releases of the software in `trunk` that represent packaged releases of the software that need to be retained. The other two are support scripts for packaging and testing.

It was mainly just me committing against the repository -- each of the releases was just created with an `svn copy` command.

It may not be best practice, but it's been easy to develop against -- I check out the build environment, which subsequently checks out trunk for me to work on. A packaging script copies out the new tag and creates a downloadable package for me when I'm ready.

How do I go about cleaning this up and bringing it into a git repository? Ideally I'd like to use best practices, and would like to retain all of the history.

I've tried using `svn2git`:

```
svn2git path-to-repo --trunk trunk --nobranches --authors=/path/to/authors.txt
```

which populates a repo with trunk for me, but I don't see any tags (`git tag` shows nothing). I'd also ideally like to have the other scripts brought over too.

My main purpose for using GIT is my development method -- sometimes I'm stuck with developing away from a test machine, and would like to commit to a test repository where I can fix bugs before pushing it further upstream. Now I just commit broken things to the central SVN repository and check out on the test machine. That obviously sucks.

I'm happy to spend some time cleaning up the SVN repo if necessary -- I'm not ready to ditch it just yet.

Answer (score 2):

Cleaning up the SVN repo will not help you, because you can't move the directories in the existing revisions and that's what you'll be importing.

I have no experience with `svn2git`, but with `git svn` I'd simply:

- Initialize trunk only:

  ```
  git svn init -A /path/to/authors.txt --prefix=svn/ -t trunk url://to/svn/root
  ```
- Manually list the tags and branches I'd like to import by manually editing the svn section so it would look like:

  ```
  [svn-remote "svn"]
  url = url://to/svn/root
  fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/svn/trunk
  fetch = build_scripts:refs/remotes/svn/build_scripts
  fetch = packager:refs/remotes/svn/packager
  tags = 0.*:refs/remotes/svn/tags/0.*
  ```

  I am not completely sure the tags line will work; if it does not, you can always list all existing tags explicitly.
- Run `git svn fetch` after everything is set up

Unfortunately when a new branch is created in the svn repo, you have to add matching pattern before fetching to git; if git-svn already fetched a revision and didn't create a branch because it didn't have a pattern for it, it won't be able to go back to it and will only import any new revisions on it. And I didn't find any way to tell it to refetch those branches.